Should I rewrite "rhetorical answers" if it still does not solve OP's question?
My 'Not an answer' flag was declined on this answer:

Can you check if your variable isHidden,inside renderCell, is getting recalculated on toggle?

My visible button is not working, how do I solve it?


The mod in question added this as the denied text:

Declined - Rhetorical questions must not be flagged; edit them and make them an answer instead.
See this Q&A: Should I not flag a rhetorical question posted as an answer?

Even though I'm not quite sure if this is actually intended as a rhetorical question, but it seems like you are expecting me to edit the answer to something like:

Your issue is caused by the isHidden variable inside renderCell not getting recalculated.

In my honest opinion, this is still not an answer. OP did not provide enough code for the answerer to be able to 'find that answer'. So then the 'question' (should be comment) becomes an invalid answer.
If I came across the suggested edit, I'll still downvote it, and might even flag it as NAA.
Should I still make the edit?

That you'd downvote it, doesn't make it not an answer or one that doesn't "solve" the issue, at least for some people. If you don't think you can reasonably edit it into an acceptable answer, then don't. Skip the whole process and cast a downvote

We'll I'm sure it does not answer OP's question, something the answerer cant see with the supplied code. From the flag popup: "It should possibly be an edit a comment...", I flagged it as that since it seems like the answerer wants to ask it, but that still makes it naa.

A wrong answer is still an answer, that's not what NAA is for.

Related on MSE: Should I not flag a rhetorical question posted as an answer?

@KevinB Technically it's a question, not an answer... those don't generally end with a question mark.

Oke I agree, but you're currently assuming the answerer actually sees this as an answer, we can't know if he's just asking since he can't comment yet. I don't care about the flag, but I don't want to make a bad answer.

They're literally asking if a particular option has been attempted to solve the problem, while, yes, that technically could be considered requesting information because that option can be represented as code, it very well could be rhetorical as well indicating that's what they think the op needs. That they were wrong isn't really relevant to whether or not it was NAA. It's just a bad answer. Why get more people involved in it?

"Why get more people involved in it?"; are referring to this question? Because I want to learn how to deal with these kind of mod feedback, and not just ignore/follow it (It's your choice to read/comment here). Anyway, the answer suggest to check "if a React prop is recalculated if its changed using a setter of an useState hook"; well yea, that the whole idea of react state/hooks/props.

No, i mean why flag it at all. The purpose of NAA is to convert things that should be comments into comments. There's no value in this one being a comment, and it could be considered rhetorical, so why send it off to a review queue at all when a downvote would serve the purpose just as well? Maybe it'd get deleted in the review queue, or it won't be, but either way it deserves a downvote that effectively accomplishes the same goal. Why would anyone edit it? it'd still be wrong.

Answers like this tend to appear mostly on bad questions that should have been closed. (Worse than average, I mean.) Focusing your efforts on question closure is usually more productive IMX.

Ah oke, as state in my other comment; I flagged it because IMHO it seem to match "It should possibly be an edit, a comment...". It still might bring value if OP answers that question, which might make the answerer better understand the issue, thats not for me to judge. Didn't see a downvote as the same action, learned another thing. Anyway thank you for your insight/info on this Kevin, highly appreciated, I've
might just misinterpreted the NAA for this case.

To be fair, a downvote on an answer will never result in deletion on its own so there is an argument there in favor of flagging, in some scenarios, i'm just not sure that's the case here. Yea, it should be deleted because it's wrong and not a good answer even if it was right, but is it so bad that we should tie up people's time with it? That's more the issue i have with it. there's a lot of answers that i think should be deleted, but the way flags work currently isn't a good solution for that. A downvote will at least put the post into a state where it can be deleted by the community.

This clearly looks like a request for more information from the asker. I don’t think it’s a suitable example for rhetorical questions.  Making the proposed edit would clearly conflict with the author’s intent of asking for clarification.

I don't agree with @Kevin. That post is NAA, and should be flagged as such. -- Kevin, please post your answer as an answer instead of a comment, so that we may downvote it.

@CrisLuengo that's kinda the whole point, why shoudl i bother writing an answer supporting a low quality answer that hsould be deleted on a question that should be deleted? this whole ordeal is a waste of everyone's time. The flag was never necessary.

"Can you check if your variable isHidden,inside renderCell, is getting recalculated on toggle?" Sure as hell looks like a "request for details blah blah blah" to me... NAA seems fine to me on NAA description alone, but that said... NAA flags get declined all the time, to the point that I don't bother ever using it and have better luck down-voting and flagging low-quality so it gets pushed to review queues where others can help get it deleted. Don't try to edit it into better shape, it's already starting from a terrible position.

That is a comment requesting clarification, not an answer.

@PresidentJamesK.Polk In this specific case I fully agree. In other cases it is still possible that an answer is worded poorly enough that it turns into something it is not, reviewers should be able to poke through that and I can see why a flag would be declined if there is a possibility of it being the case. Not here though, this should have been a no-brainer.

@Gimby: agree 100%. The presence of a question in an answer is not, in itself, enough to render it NAA. The full content of the answer, in the context of the question, must be analyzed, and the benefit of doubt should be accorded to the answerer.

Related: Are answers speculating on what the problem might be considered answers?  re: flagging or editing answers that are written as questions or guesses.

You were right to flag that answer, as it is not an answer. It is an attempt by a newer user to bypass the reputation requirement for leaving comments.
The ability to leave a comment comes with 50 reputation points, whereas anyone at any reputation can post an answer.
Perhaps the Moderator was just having an off day.


When should I comment?
You should submit a comment if you want to:

Request clarification from the author;




Why and how are some answers deleted?
Answer posts that do not fundamentally answer the question may be removed.
This includes answers that are:

commentary on the question or other answers



commentary on the question Many times I came across a question I couldn't answer, however, I can add my test or more info as Question Extension to help others to answer it, is that wrong? what are the alternatives? comment is not enough Check this NAA Here

Hi Mustafa, the situation I am addressing here is a specific instance of someone using an answer because they did not have access to the comment feature. As a result, their content was a single sentence question requesting post clarification. Note that the help pages state "may be removed", not will be removed; in certain edge cases, there is no reason for deletion. The case you highlight is a different type of issue altogether. Perhaps that would be better suited as its own question on meta, as it addresses troubleshooting in a different facet; namely, that it does verify OP code.

Thanks, for your clarification, I got it, you might ask me why I didn't make it as wiki, because I may find the answer and edit it to be an answer but never for getting reputation, I have many solved answers without an accept/upvote I never asked to

@MustafaMutasim Please do not use code formatting for things that are not code. For what it’s worth, the highlighted words do not seem to be special, so most likely they should not have any special formatting to begin with.

@MisterMiyagi, OK,I will reduce it to minimal

@MustafaMutasim If you want to extend the question, the correct way to do that is by editing the question. Although I'd be very careful when doing that, since you should not change the author's intent. If your potential edit could conflict with author's intent, better just leave a comment asking author to edit. Answers are the wrong place to add info to question, and the "answer" you linked should be deleted.

@Yksisarvinen, So, the workaround is a Comment + External Image link, Thanks!
